# how to improve the interaction between two Hash Map in java?

Tags: java, hashmap

In the below code I am fetching the objects from the hive and passing the `tbl_guid` to fetch the matches in Mysql and  Map will be returned as contains `Map<tbl_guid ,uniqueseq>`, then the on the based of `tbl_guid` as key already present the map `dRListMap` value `List<DeletedRecord> DeletedRecord` object property `tbl_guid` will be updated with fetched the uniqueseq fetched from the mysql.

Why am I replacing the `tbl_guid` with `uniqueSeq` fetching from the mysql because the on the based with small no corresponding to every `tbl_guid` which will stored in the HBase later of this, that part of code is not required herein discussion so I haven't posted? I would like to know where is enhancement is required current code.

1st Method

```
String sql = String.format("select * from %s .HiveTable limit 12", dbName);   
Map<String, List<DeletedRecord>> dRListMap = new HashMap<>();
try (Statement stmt = hiveConnection.createStatement(); ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql)) {
    int i=0;
    while ((rs.next())) {
        DeletedRecord delRecord = new DeletedRecord(rs.getString(1), rs.getString(2), rs.getString(3),
                rs.getString(4), rs.getDate(5));

        String key = rs.getString(2);
        List<DeletedRecord> recordList = dRListMap.get(key) == null ? new ArrayList<>() : dRListMap.get(key);

        recordList.add(delRecord);
        dRListMap.put(key, recordList);
        i++;
        if (i == 10) {
            CommonService.fetchUniquForTblGuid(dRListMap);
            i=0;

        }

    }if(i>0) {
        CommonService.fetchUniquForTblGuid(dRListMap);
    }

} catch (Exception ee) {
    LOGGER.error("Exception occurred while fetching the records from table_name", ee);
}
```

2nd Method

```
public static void fetchUniquForTblGuid(Map<String, List<DeletedRecord>> dRListMap) {
    List<List<DeletedRecord>> valueList = Collections.list(Collections.enumeration(dRListMap.values()));
    List<String> values = valueList.stream().flatMap(Collection::stream).map(DeletedRecord::getTblGuid)
            .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));

    Map<String, String> tblSeqMap = getTheUniqueNoForGuids(values);
    System.out.println(dRListMap);

    for (Map.Entry<String, String> map : tblSeqMap.entrySet()) {

        if (dRListMap.containsKey(map.getKey())) {

            dRListMap.get(map.getKey()).forEach((DeletedRecord del)->del.setTblGuid(map.getValue()));
        }
    }
    System.out.println(dRListMap);
    dRListMap.clear();
}
```

3rd Method

```
public static Map<String, String> getTheUniqueNoForGuids(List<String> tableGuids) {
    Map<String, String> guidVsUnique = new HashMap<>();
    String tableGuidStr = listToCommaDelimitedString(tableGuids);
    String fetchthequniforguid = "select distinct tbl_guid,unique_sequ from " + sqlProp.getProperty("database")
            + ".mysql table where tbl_guid in (" + tableGuidStr + ")";

    try (PreparedStatement prep = mysqlConnection.prepareStatement(fetchthequniforguid);
            ResultSet res = prep.executeQuery()) {

        LOGGER.info(String.format("Mysql query %s ", fetchthequniforguid));

        while (res.next()) {

            guidVsUnique.put(res.getString(1), res.getString(2));

        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {

        LOGGER.info(String.format("Error while executing %s in mysql and occurred %s ", fetchthequniforguid, e));
    }

    return guidVsUnique;
}
```

4th Method

```
public static String listToCommaDelimitedString(List<String> requestIds) {
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

    if (requestIds.size() == 1)
        buffer.append("'" + requestIds.get(0) + "'");
    else if (requestIds.size() > 1) {

        buffer.append("'");

        for (int i = 0; i < requestIds.size(); i++) {

            if (i == requestIds.size() - 1)
                buffer.append(requestIds.get(i) + "'");
            else
                buffer.append(requestIds.get(i) + "', '");

        }
    }

    return buffer.toString();
}
```

Comment: 4 Method 

public static String listToCommaDelimitedString(List<String> requestIds) {
  StringJoiner whereClause=new StringJoiner("', '","'","'");
  requestIds.parallelStream().forEach(whereClause::add);    
  
  return whereClause.toString();
 }